# Plotting points onto a JPG raster map in R

Tags: r, ggmap, rmaps

I have a fictional map and want to plot points onto it.

The map is a fictional map from a fantasy book, so has no spatial reference.
The points will show where events from the book have taken place.

I essentially wish to create an interactive map, that displays main events from the book on the fictional map.

Similar to the one created for Lord of the Rings here

http://lotrproject.com/map/#zoom=3&lat=-1315.5&lon=1500&layers=BTTTTT

Would this be possible in R and if so, how?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you done any research yourself, i.e. is there anything that you have already have tried? Also, why [dictionary]?

Comment: Hi there. I have tried plotting points to the image in Arcmap, which I've managed to do rather crudely. I have been researching into all the available mapping packages and tutorials, but they all use real base maps with spatial references. I have a JPG image with no spatial reference, hence I asked here to see if it would be possible in R. Dictionary was tagged by mistake and removed.